# How to replace words following certain character and extract rest with REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

Assume that i have the following sentence

```
select PathSquares from tblPathFinding where RouteId=470 
and StartingSquareId=267 and ExitSquareId=13
```

Now i want to replace words followed by `=` and get the rest of the sentence

Lets say i want to replace following word of `=` with `%`

Words are separated with space character

So this sentence would become

```
select PathSquares from tblPathFinding where RouteId=%
and StartingSquareId=% and ExitSquareId=%
```

With which regex i can achieve this ?

.net 4.5 C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind to match all the non-space or word chars which are just after to `=` symbol . Replacing the matched chars with `%` wiil give you the desired output.

```
@"(?<==)\S+"
```

OR

```
@"(?<==)\w+"
```

**Replacement string:**

```
%
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zM9vD5/3)

```
string str = @"select PathSquares from tblPathFinding where RouteId=470 
and StartingSquareId=267 and ExitSquareId=13";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<==)\S+", "%");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/M3vZbN)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<==)` Asserts that the match must be preceded by an `=` symbol.
- `\w+` If yes, then match the following one or more word characters.